# Oracle SQL Developer - Format setting like toad

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

how to make SQL Developer to format my PL/SQL code like TOAD.
Because every time, I need to get help from other peers to format my PL/SQL code.

Comment: You want to format what?

Comment: Yes.. my PL/SQL code. previously I used TOAD in my previous project. But in the new project , they use SQL developer , when I press ctrl+f7- code is getting formatted but,its not same as TOAD, I like the code format of TOAD, is there any way we can change setting in SQLdeveloper so that it formats the code as TOAD does ? Kindly help, (Note : let me know if my question is not a productive one, will delete it  :) )

Comment: Don't recall the complete path, but you can customize the editing behavior of SQL-Developer. Look for Options and Edit (I recall changing the use of spaces instead of tab chars, but that was quite some time ago).

Comment: Thank you FDavidov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the formatting, so you can adapt it yourself to the formatting TOAD has. Go to the menu

Tools - Preferences - Database - SQL Formatter - Oracle Formatting

Click on "edit", and then you can change the alignments, indentation, line breaks etc.

Might take a while to customize it, but you can change everything according to your preferences.